# Automatic redirect from files in folder to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-403

On my server I have directory "reset", which contains 3 files *index.php , 1.php, 2.php*.
index.php includes the following code:

```
if (condition) {
        include_once "1.php";
    } else {
        include_once "2.php";
    }
```

User still can open files for inclusion directly from directory *reset/1.php*
How to automatically redirect user from this files to *index.php* ?

Comment: In `1.php`, if current address in browser address contains `1.php`, issue a redirect header to `index.php`.

Comment: @Davinder Thank you, I think that's the best solution, you may post it as an answer to make question accomplished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//if current executing file is not 1.php
if(strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], "1.php") === FALSE){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

If in the filename of script currently executing, `1.php` is found, redirect to `index.php`.

http://codepad.org/dE0zplUN *Note, in codepad.org sample, I have changed `1.php` to `t.php`, because as of writing this, codepad.org site uses this file name as the main/executing script.*
Edit this to any filename you  required.

You could also have a look at $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

Answer (score 0):

You can set a header in PHP to automatically redirect the user to index.php. Note that triggering a 403 in unnecessary in this case: `header("Location: ./index.php");`

Good Luck!
-TP

Comment: Because of include function your solution will cause redirect loop

Comment: Then I misunderstood what you are doing.. after re-reading, correct me if im wrong - you want to be able to show the file as long as it's been included from reset.php, but if they try to access it directly, THEN redirect back to reset.php ?

Comment: alrighty, was going to say check the referrer. good luck in the future.